# Resize new image by giving size in opencart

Tags: php, html, css, image, opencart

How to resize image by giving size, I will use opencart for my new site but in that some problem. When I upload image of product (200x230) and my cropping size is (405x130) it will generate new image with (405x130 but the image content is display with original content and around the image set white background, I want to resize my image with new size without white background so anyone help me for this.
**Original image**

[image]

**Resize Image**

[image]

**i want like this**

[image]

Comment: Opencart worked correctly, what you want to be the result? can you post the image you wish to be generated?

Comment: dear  Mojtaba Sabeti i know  Opencart worked correctly. but i want to change for site iif original image is 200x230 and it will resize 405x130 so it will be like 3ed image of my question i think you understand now. thanks to all

Comment: don't want to use css?

Comment: ya its possible with css but i want to resize image like this...in css image original size is not change so . i want to resize image to 405x130 form 200x230

Comment: Here, will bad image clarity with according to you want. but, I think, You can to auto type image resize. Please check & follow this tutorials. http://www.opencartnews.com/tutorials/auto-type-opencart-image-resize/